# spread imshow heatmap over limits of axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have an array of x,y positions at one time step and but I know over time this range will expand (as set by the image range already). Is there a way to make the rest of the grid over the range be 0 until it is populated. My understanding is that the x,y positions or the map itself from np.histogram2d will need to be restructured on a new grid of a different size, though I'm not sure how. So far I have:

```
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
ax.imshow(heatmap.T, origin='lower',extent=extent,cmap='cubehelix')
ax.set_xlim([20,220])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
```

But this results in a confined region. I want to make the white space black basically, until the new x,y positions populate them at some later time step.

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the extent of the histogram independently of the data passed in to `numpy.histogram2d`, specify the bin locations as arrays.

For example, something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Known ranges for the histogram and plot
xmin, xmax = 20, 220
ymin, ymax = -1, 1

# Generate some random data
x = np.random.normal(48, 5, 100)
y = np.random.normal(0.4, 0.1, 100)

# Create arrays specifying the bin edges
nbins = 50
xbins = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nbins)
ybins = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nbins)

# Create the histogram using the specified bins
data, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xbins, ybins))

# Plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data.T, origin='lower', cmap='cubehelix', aspect='auto',
          interpolation='nearest', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])

ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.show()
```

[image]